# Avoid inserting duplicates by using ForeignKey in m:n relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx Julie Lerman is explaining how to avoid inserting duplicate entities into the database in `1:n` relationships by setting the `foreign-key` instead of the `navigation property`.

I have the same problem, but with a `m:n` relationship.

The problem is, that I can't just set the foreign-key-id because I have a list of foreign-keys.

Is it possible to use the same method like this: `ICollection<int> TopicIds`?

How can I use this method to work with `m:n` relationships?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here are the entities:

```
public class Artist : PersistenceEntity
{
    public Artist()
    {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}

public class Genre : PersistenceEntity
{

    public Genre() 
    {
        Artists = new List<Artist>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Artist> Artist { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, could you show your entities?

Comment: Well if this was DB first you'd just create a connector table with the primary keys of each of the other tables and make the combination of both the primary key of that table with foreign keys out to the other tables.

Comment: @octavioccl: I've added the entities to the post

Comment: @juharr: It's code first :-)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have field for foreign key, then you cannot use foreign-key based approach. But you still can use entity state based approach. I.e. if you are creating new Artist and want to provide some existing genres, then first attempt will be

```
var artist = new Artist }
   Name = "Offspring",
   Genres = new List<Genre> { rockGenre, punkGenre }
};

db.Artists.Add(artist);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But that will put whole graph into *Added* state (and both genre objects). So you should specify state of genre objects manually:

```
db.Genres.Attach(rockGenre);
db.Genres.Attach(punkGenre);
var artist = new Artist { Name = "Offspring" };
db.Artists.Add(artist);
artist.Genres = new List<Genre> { rockGenre, punkGenre };
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or

```
var artist = new Artist }
   Name = "Offspring",
   Genres = new List<Genre> { rockGenre, punkGenre }
};

db.Artists.Add(artist);
db.Entry(rockGenre).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
db.Entry(punkGenre).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in update a many to many relationship using the navigation properties, in fact, if you are configuring your [relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) as EF proposes to do (avoiding to map the junction table in case you don't need to add additional columns to that table) is the only way to do it.

So if you have a collection of genres ids, and you want to related those genres with an artist, you could do this.

```
var genresids=new List<int>(){1,3,6,9};
var genres= context.Genres.Where(g=>genresids.Contains(g.GenreId));
var artist=context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(); //Find an artirst
foreach(var genre in genres)
{
   artist.Genres.Add(genre);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, if you decide to map the junction table as an entity, you are going to need to create two one to many relationships to replace your many to many configuration. Your junction entity would be like this:

```
public class GenreArtist
{
    [Key,Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Artist")]
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }

    [Key,Column(Order=2), ForeignKey("Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

And you must change the type of collection navigation properties to `GenreArtist`:

```
public virtual ICollection<GenreArtist> GenreArtists{ get; set; }
```

With that model, you can relate multiples genres to an artist this way:

```
var genresids=new List<int>(){1,3,6,9};
var artist=context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(); //Find the artirst you want to update
foreach(var genreId in genresids)
{
   artist.GenreArtists.Add(new GenreArtist{ArtistId=artist.ArtistId, GenereId=genreId});
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

But I really believe this is not necessary if your junction table is not going to have more columns. Anyways, in this [link](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/) you can find very good reasons that support the idea of mapping that table.